# Spark runs only 8 tasks and using only 2 nodes despite having 20 nodes cluster, we are using dynamic allocation for this job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

we are using spark to run our transformation i.e join, groupBy etc
there are two datasets 1. big dataset (20gb) 2. small dataset (250mb) while joining them spark caches them both its fine to take 8 tasks for small dataset but for big dataset its taking 8 tasks and using 2 nodes whereas i have 20 nodes of cluster.

added spark.default.parallelism property but no use : i guess this works for only rdd

[image: spark ui image]

Comment: Hello @Aashish. Please give a minimal example of your code to help people answer your question. You will find guidance here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @BertrandGazanion we use dataiku, so we usually do not write code instead we use visual recipe and select engine as spark

Comment: you should  broadcast  small data across and then hash join .

Comment: Please post us the output of: `sc._conf.getAll()`.

Comment: hi @sandeeprawat i have tried to broadcast but my parquet seems to be huge when compressed it is 250 mb but when it goes into memory it turns out to be  1341.6 MB.

which always gives me spark out of memory error

Comment: Just a gentle reminder. Spark doesn't care about nodes it cares about executors. It may be only running on 2 nodes but could have N executors per node. Also, if spark can avoid it, it tries not to perform a shuffle. Shuffles are very expensive and should be avoided when possible. In short, you see this as only 8 task on two nodes while spark's catalyst engine may see this as the optimal way to process the data in terms of runtime.

Comment: its is resolved now, the issue was with (tool's) dynamic allocation and when static allocation is added it takes required resources. 

Thanks all for the right direction that got me the solution